# Can someone explain in-order traversal of binary tree recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I have some code to traverse a binary tree in-order recursively.

```
def IN_DFS(node, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = []
    if not node:
        return result
    Solution.IN_DFS(node.left, result)

    result.append(node.val)

    Solution.IN_DFS(node.right, result)

    return result
```

I need some help understanding what is happening. I understand recursion, and I know how to traverse a binary tree in-order iteratively, but can't seem to see what is happening for this recursive solution.

So if 'node' is not None, we are calling the recursive function on node.left until we reach a lead node, in which case node.left is None, and we move to the next line 'result.append(node.val)'? - is this right?

Then the recursive function is called on 'node.right'?

So say we reach the first node.left leaf node, add its value to 'result' then go back up one step to its parent, add its value to 'result', then check its right child?

I don't think the above is right- anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. So if 'node' is not None, we are calling the recursive function on node.left until we reach a lead node, in which case node.left is None, and we move to the next line 'result.append(node.val)'? - is this right?-
   **Yes, you got it right here.**
2. So say we reach the first node.left leaf node, add its value to 'result' then go back up one step to its parent, add its value to 'result', then check its right child?
   **No, you move to the right subtree(the right node of the current node.)**

Comment: Thanks Arpit, that makes sense. One more thing I don't quite understand. So let's say we get to the leftmost leaf node, after processing it, we then go to the node.right, but when is the parent node itself added? Because the parent node will always have children, so in the recursion I don't see where we would add parent.node.val?

Comment: When all children have been traversed. suppose, you have a node with it's left subtree added, the program will then retrace to the parent node and traverse it's right subtree. Within the right subtree,  if there is another left subtree, it will be traversed first and so on. When all of them (left and right subtrees) have been traversed the program retraces to orignal node and adds it.

Comment: you can get a deeper understanding [link](https://youtu.be/F2SksNIg0os)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation- I did understand how the tree is traversed, where I am having difficulty is seeing how the code achieves the traversal you have mentioned. For example, I don't understand the first recursion call- let's say we get to a leaf node, this means the next node is empty, and so we hit the base case, where we will return 'result', which is empty? Then the next line of code gets called, which is to append the value of that leaf node. Where do we go from here? I understand in theory we go back to the parent then to the right child, but how does the code achieve this??

Comment: where we will return 'result', which is empty? - yes. Then the next line of code gets called, which is to append the value of that leaf node. - yes. Where do we go from here? - you go to the very next statement in the code  `Solution.IN_DFS(node.right, result)` i.e. you pass the node to the right of the node you just appended in the result(say RIGHT). and the program again carries on as usual. It first checks the left node of  RIGHT.left , then RIGHT and then RIGHT.right

Comment: Thanks Arpit, but after appending the left leaf node, do we not need to append its parent first? Before the right.child? I don't see where we are appending the parent node of the left.child

Comment: ` Solution.IN_DFS(node.left, result)` this code will keep on executing till the leaf node is reached. Once we are at the leaf node, the left child will be null. this is where `if not node:
        return result` condition check comes in. It will backtrack to the last stack entry in memory which would be `Solution.IN_DFS(parent.left, result)`. From here it will go to next line of code i.e. `result.append(parent.val)` and then to `Solution.IN_DFS(parent.right, result)`

Comment: the code `result.append(parent.val)` will append the value to result before moving on to the right subtree.

Comment: Omg that makes so much sense, thank you for explaining. One thing- why does 'return result' cause backtrack? I understand that as we traverse the node.left until child nodes that each one is being added to the recursion stack- but why does 'result result' call on the latest item in the stack? Is this just how it works?

Comment: Because in my mind once we reach the left leaf node, result = [] ; and if we return result, we are just returning the empty [] -?

Comment: Backtracking is caused because the current function call is in stack and the function has not completed.  Any function call is expected to return the control to the caller. So, when we call the `return result`, it gives this value to the calling method. e.g `int res = Add(a, b)` this first calls the Add(a,b), gets a return value and then assignment to rest takes place. This is how the recursive calls behave. each return statement, returns the control to the calling statement.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Arpit, extremely helpful! One last thing, I promise! When we call "Solution.IN_DFS(node.left, result)" - this places IN_DFS(node.left) in the stack as partially complete... and we will keep placing these function calls in the stack, until we reach the leaf node, at which point they get called in order. Is this right? Thanks

Comment: this places IN_DFS(node.left) in the stack as partially complete - nothing is dkept as partially complete here. It just stores the current state of the method in the stack and starts executing the internal calls. Once a leaf node is reached, the backtracking begins in the LIFO order. Whatever method state is the topmost on stack, the returned result is applied to it's processing and the method execution is completed. The new return value is passed to the next topmost method call and so on.